# Paging Datastax java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

Can someone point me to a detailed documentation how paging is implemented, with page and page state? I have gone through https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/paging/

But how is it implemented internally?

Is the coordinator drawing data and does a limit offset query as the data is drawn out from replicas sequentially for every page request?

Or are the saving the file cursor and doing a RandomAccess? If so can I get that back from the driver and use it later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you mentioned is the most up-to-date about pagination with the DataStax Java driver. You can also read [this blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0), which is a bit old, but still valid.

> Is the coordinator drawing data and does a limit offset query [...] ?

No. Actually, there is no "offset query" in Cassandra, see [CASSANDRA-6511](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6511). This is also covered in the [driver documentation on paging](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/paging/#offset-queries).

> Or are the saving the file cursor and doing a RandomAccess? If so can I get that back from the driver and use it later on?

Yes to both. The paging state exposed by the driver is meant to be used in exactly that way; again, this is explained in the [driver documentation on paging](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/paging/#saving-and-reusing-the-paging-state).